# Extracting random characters from a string, then printing the remainder.

Tags: python, list, random, python-3.x

As part of my course at university I am learning python. A task I have been trying to complete is to write a program that will print out random letters and their corresponding positions in "antidisestablishmentarianism". It will then print the remaining letters on a single line.

I have been trying to do this in probably a crazy weird roundabout way - populating a list with the chosen values and removing these characters from the original.

I realize my program is probably all wrong and broken; I only started learning lists today!

```
import random
word = "antidisestablishmentarianism"
wordList =["antidisestablishmentarianism"]

print("The Word is:",word,"\n")

lengthWord = len(word)
usedValues=[]
for i in range(5):
    position = random.randrange(0,lengthWord)
    print("word[",position, "]\t", word [position])
    usedValues=[position]
for ch in wordList:
    wordList.remove([usedValues])
print("The remaining letters are",WordList, sep='')
```

Comment: Do the extracted characters need to be in order?

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem is that you're creating and manipulating your `worldList` and `usedValues` lists incorrectly.

To create a list of characters as `wordList` use `list(word)`. To add a used index to `usedValues` use `usedValues.append(position)`. There's also an issue with how you remove the used values from the word list.

Here's your code with those errors fixed:

```
import random
word = "antidisestablishmentarianism"
wordList = list(word)

print("The Word is:",word,"\n")

lengthWord = len(word)
usedValues=[]
for i in range(5):
    position = random.randrange(0,lengthWord)
    print("word[",position, "]\t", word[position])
    usedValues.append(position)

for index in usedValues:
    wordList.pop(index)

print("The remaining letters are",WordList, sep='')
```

This will mostly work. However, there's still a logic error. If you get the same random position twice in the first loop, you'll report the same character each time. However, when you remove them from the list later, you'll end up popping two different letters. Similarly, if you remove an letter from near the start of the word, the indexes you remove later on will be incorrect. You can even get a `IndexError` if one of the last positions selected was near the end of the word.

One fix would be to remove the selected values from the list immediately, within the first loop. You'll need to explicitly call `len` each cycle then (since it changes each time through) but other than that everything should work correctly.

Or here's how I'd solve the problem. Instead of picking five specific indexes and removing them from the list, I'd `random.shuffle` a list of all the indexes and take the first five. The rest can then be either printed out in their random order, or sorted first to give the impression of the letters being removed from the original word.

```
import random
word = "antidisestablishmentarianism"

indexes = list(range(len(word)))
random.shuffle(indexes)

for i in indexes[:5]:
    print("word[%d] is '%s'" % (i, word[i]))

rest = sorted(indexes[5:]) # or just use indexes[5:] to keep random order
print("The remaining letters are '%s'" % "".join(word[i] for i in rest))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code as it stands. Firstly, this line:

```
wordList =["antidisestablishmentarianism"]
```

doesn't do what you think - it actually creates a list containing the single item `"antidisestablishmentarianism"`. To convert a string into a list of characters, you can use `list()` - and since you've already have the variable `word`, there's no need to type the word in again.

On a side note, `wordList` isn't a very good variable name. Apart from the fact that it uses camelCase rather than the more pythonic underscore_separated style, what you actually want here is a list of the *characters* in the word.

So, that line can be replaced with:

```
characters = list(word)
```

Moving on ... this line:

```
lengthWord = len(word)
```

is redundant - you only reference `lengthWord` once in your code, so you might as well just replace that reference with `len(word)` where you use it.

Your line:

```
    usedValues=[position]
```

also isn't doing what you think: it's *replacing* `usedValues` entirely, with a list containing only the latest position in your loop. To append a value to a list, use `list.append()`:

```
    used_positions.append(position)
```

(I've given the variable a more accurate name). Your next problem is this block:

```
for ch in wordList:
    wordList.remove([usedValues])
```

First of all, you really want to check each of the positions you've previously stored, not each of the characters in the word. Your use of `list.remove()` is also wrong: you can't give a list of values to remove like that, but anyway `list.remove()` will remove the first instance of a value from a list, and what you want to do is remove the item at a particular position, which is what `list.pop()` is for:

```
for position in sorted(used_positions, reverse=True):
    characters.pop(position)
```

We're using a copy of `used_positions` sorted in reverse so that when we remove an item, the remaining positions in `used_positions` don't slide out of alignment with what's left of `characters`[*].

Your final problem is the last line:

```
print("The remaining letters are",WordList, sep='')
```

If you want to print the contents of a list separated by `''`, this isn't the way to do it. Instead, you need `str.join()`:

```
print("The remaining letters are", "".join(characters))
```

Putting all of those changes into practice, and tidying up a little, we end up with:

```
import random
word = "antidisestablishmentarianism"
characters = list(word)

print("The Word is:", word, "\n")

used_positions = []

for i in range(5):
    position = random.randrange(0, len(word))
    print("word[",position, "]\t", word[position])
    used_positions.append(position)

for position in sorted(used_positions, reverse=True):
    characters.pop(position)

print("The remaining letters are", "".join(characters))
```

[*] In fact, this throws up another problem: what if your code chooses the same position twice? I'll leave you to think about that one.